# Java - Making the painting program cleaner

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint, graphics2d

I am writing a simple paint program. The problem is that when you increase the `setStroke(new BasicStroke(size));` to a large number, the line gets all messed up.  I am writing to a buffered Image with graphics 2D.

[image: Line all messed up]

Any ideas on how to make the line look cleaner?

Code:

```
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
            dot=false;


            if(graphics2D != null && paint.erase==false)
            {
                currentX = e.getX();
                currentY = e.getY();
                graphics2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(size));
            graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);

            repaint();

    }
  }
}
```

This draws on a buffered image.

Comment: It would be nice to see some code with this, just so we know what we're supposed to be 'improving'

Comment: @John Updated the question with code. Graphics2D=the bufferedImage.createGraphics();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the behavior of the default line cap which is `CAP_SQUARE`. Try using the [`BasicStroke(float width, int cap, int join)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html#BasicStroke-float-int-int-) constructor:

```
new BasicStroke(
    size,
    BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,
    BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND
);
```

You will get even better behavior of you use a [`java.awt.geom.Path2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html) for the duration of the entire <kbd>mouse down</kbd>`...`<kbd>mouse up</kbd> sequence. Then each line in the sequence is joined.